# Playlist made from youtube is different in 'music.youtube.com'. How can I get playlist title from this playlist?

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, youtube

playlist code is different in '`music.youtbue.com`'
prefix 'PL-' in youtube 
but, '`RDCLAK5uy_`' in music youtube

I tried to retrieve title from 'RDCLAK5uy_' playlist.
But there is no information until I found now.

```
public void PlayListTitle()
    {
        youtubeapi.Search(this.name, 10, YoutubeAPIManager.YoutubeSearchOrderFilter.none, YoutubeAPIManager.YoutubeSafeSearchFilter.none, customFilter, OnSearchDone);
    }

    void OnSearchDone(YoutubeData[] results)
    {
        LoadVideosOnUI(results);

        Debug.Log("Yes, We have results");

        for (int x = 0; x < results.Length; x++)
        {
            Debug.Log(results[x].snippet.publishedAt);
            Debug.Log(results[x].snippet.channelId);
            Debug.Log(results[x].snippet.title);
            Debug.Log(results[x].snippet.channelTitle);
            Debug.Log(results[x].snippet.tags);
        }
    }

    void LoadVideosOnUI(YoutubeData[] videoList)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < videoList.Length; x++)
        {

            if (x==0)
            {
                titleText.text = videoList[x].snippet.title;
                Debug.Log("이프들어옴");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I get title from prefix 'RDCLAK5uy_' playlist?

Comment: Can you provide a URL sample of the playlist you want retrieve? I can get the title of a given playlist that comes from youtube main site or music.youtube; but, in your question I understand that you retrieve the title *just* by the prefix, am I wrong?